# Base class reference in initializer list in C++

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, initializer-list

I have four classes.

```
class ABase {
};
class ADerived : public ABase{
}

class BBase {
   ABase & a;
};
class BDerived : public BBase{

};
```

Since the reference is of ABase class I can have any object type ABase/ADerived. Now, I want to have object a of type ABase in BBase but of type ADerived in BDerived.

The thing is they have to be initialized in the initializer list. How can I make this work ?
I do not want to switch to new BBase()/ new BDerived()
I want to keep using reference instead of pointers.
It seems the references are less powerful, at least in this regard.

Comment: Please show how you are using the classes now, including initializer list.

Comment: What is the actual problem your design is supposed to solve? Why does the `BDerived` class need an explicit reference to an `ADerived` object? Can't your problem be solved through normal polymorphism? And why does your design mandate references over (smart) pointers?

Comment: Unrelated: References are groovy, but a reference cannot be reassigned. This makes an assignment operator for a class with a reference member potentially troublesome.

Comment: Right now, `a` is private, so you can't do `ADerived ad; BDerived db{ad};` and you don't have a public conversion constructor making it for you.

Comment: Where is the `ABase` or `ADerived` coming from?